# lines appearing in render

Tags: rendering

[image][image]Im very new to Blender, after creating a character animation (using Mixamo) im trying to render this so i can use within Davinci resolve, however im seeing these lines in the final render, any idea why im seeing these, and what things i can look at to resolve

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. No I have no idea. Not enough details.

Comment: Please give us some idea of your rendering set-up.. are you shooting on transparent film? Are there any scene-elements that might be responsible for shadows? Can you show us the scene in its simple, non-rendered state?

Comment: Hi sure yes,its really simple (and ive only been using Blender for a few days) wasnt aware i could create a transparent background) so i mate a mesh with green material for green screening it out in edit, however its literally the camera, a point light the character and the green screen

Comment: I think it maybe be motion blur causing this, ive disabled and its fine on a frame render, will try re render the animation and see

Comment: (out of subject, but if you use a green barckground to then key it out, you most likely don't need that, just render on transparent background instead)

Comment: Thanks for that L0Lock, i did try this with PNG initially but stupidly i had selected RGB, may help if i chose RGBA to include the Alpha channel .. durr - cheers